# Split one object into multiple object by ID

Tags: arrays, object

I have an object of the following structure

```
const obj = {
  [name-1]: 'Peter',
  [name-2]: 'Mark',
  [name-3]: 'Rich',

  [age-1]: 25,
  [age-2]: 30,
  [age-3]: 45
}
```

I need to split it into 3 separate object like that

```
const obj1 = {
[name-1]: 'Peter',
[age-1]: 25,
 }

const obj2 = {
[name-2]: 'Mark',
[age-2]: 30,
 }

const obj3 = {
[name-3]: 'Rich',
[age-3]: 45,
 }
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you try anything so far ?

Comment: I didn't come up with anything worth sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Begin by getting entries of the input object using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
2. [`Reduce over`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the entries generated in step 1
3. For each iteration's current value [`split by`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) delimiter `'-'`
4. Reduce it to an object, [`the object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will act as a lookup store
5. Post doing that just [`extract the values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the lookup.
6. [`Transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the individual entries back to its individual object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = {
  'name-1': 'Peter',
  'name-2': 'Mark',
  'name-3': 'Rich',

  'age-1': 25,
  'age-2': 30,
  'age-3': 45
};

const groupedResult = Object.values(Object.entries(obj).reduce((r, c) => {
    const [key, val] = c;
    const split = key.split('-');

    if (!r[split[1]]) {
      r[split[1]] = [c];
    } else {
      r[split[1]].push(c);
    }

    return r;
  }, Object.create(null)))
  .map((value) => Object.fromEntries(value));

console.log(groupedResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so very much I wouldn't have figured out that myself